# If I create an application using AVX2 will it run on other machines?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, avx2

I am building an application that has an algorithm that takes a lot of time to complete at runtime, so I was thinking of using AVX2 to speed things up. But I don't know if the application would run in the same fast manner in a user's machine, or if it would run in their machine at all.

Comment: If a target CPU doesn't support AVX2, your app will crash with *Illegal instruction*.

Comment: If you can't assume AVX2, you need to check CPUID and set a function pointer, or something similar.  Google `runtime CPU dispatching`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not run on CPU that has no AVX2 support. Therefore before you start the algorithm, you must query the CPU for AVX2 support. Your application must be able to proceed if the answer is no by running AVX or even just SSE2.